# How to setValue multiSelect webix

Tags: webix

How to setValue multiSelect webix
it's my code:

```
$$('systemId').setValue(personItem.hSystemId.id);
```

it's doesn't work for me

code of my combo:

```
{
                                            view: "multiselect",
                                            name: "systemId",
                                            id: "systemId",
                                            label:"Система",
                                            align:"top",
                                            placeholder: 'Выберите систему',                                            
                                            options: {
                                                buttonText: "Выбрать",
                                                button: "Approve",
                                                url: "/adminstrator/ws/person/systemCombo",
                                                body: {
                                                    template: "#value#"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$$('systemId').setValue(personItem.hSystemId.id); 
$$('systemId').refresh();
```

Please try this

Comment: as it is pro version, not able to test it .

Comment: but i have pro version cause multicombo and multiselect work

Answer (score 1):

Well, i think that you need to pass your "id" in the "setValue" as a string in order to make it function. Please check the snippet: http://webix.com/snippet/760eddf8 Hope it works.